# @Html.DropDownListFor does not set default selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Can´t figure out why can´t set a default value here to be displayed:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.storeLocations, new SelectList(Model.storeLocations, "id",
"caminhoRepositorio", Model.idArmazenamento), new { @class = "largeField" })
```

The dropdown had the folowing configuration:

```
 <select class="largeField" id="storeLocations" name="storeLocations">
      <option value="2">c:/item1</option>
      <option value="3">d:/item2</option>
</select>
```

as a object "Model.idArmazenamento" I´ve already tried with int and string ("2" ou 2).
Can´t get a default value selected

Comment: I don´t want to set it using JQuery like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678145/dropdownlistfor-does-not-set-selected-value. Why is this behavior

Comment: Are you sure that `Model.idArmazenamento` is not null? Try writing it in the view to see its output.

Comment: It is not null. I am getting the value

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the same object to store the selected value and to show the options?
Try to use a different model field:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStoreLocations, new SelectList(Model.storeLocations, "id",
"caminhoRepositorio", Model.idArmazenamento), new { @class = "largeField" })
```

Comment: Just Add a variable not [required] in my model to store this value. easier

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work in a very old style:

```
<td>
    <select class="largeField" id="storeLocations" name="storeLocations">                         
        @foreach (var location in Model.storeLocations)
        {
            if (location.id == Model.idArmazenamento) { 
                <option value="@location.id" selected="@location.id">@location.caminhoRepositorio</option>
            } else {
                <option value="@location.id">@location.caminhoRepositorio</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</td>
```